# Testing broadcasts in AngularJS and Testacular

Tags: testing, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm using the [angular-http-auth](https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth) module which intercepts 401 responses. This module broadcasts `event:auth-loginRequired` if there is a 401 response which can be received with $on(). But how can I test this?

```
beforeEach(inject(function($injector, $rootScope) {
  $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
  myApi = $injector.get('myApi');
  scope = $rootScope.$new();
  spyOn($scope, '$on').andCallThrough();
}));
describe('API Client Test', function() {
  it('should return 401', function() {
    $httpBackend.when('GET', myApi.config.apiRoot + '/user').respond(401, '');
    myApi.get(function(error, success) {
      // this never gets triggered as 401 are intercepted
    });
    scope.$on('event:auth-loginRequired', function() {
      // This works!
      console.log('fired');
    });

    // This doesn't work
    expect($scope.$on).toHaveBeenCalledWith('event:auth-loginRequired', jasmine.any(Function));

    $httpBackend.flush();
  });
});
```

Comment: So do you want to test the event is fired in case of 401 or that somebody really listens for the event?

Comment: I want to make sure the event is fired, yes. In the E2E test I can test the listeners.

Comment: In your `spyOn()` and `expect()` you have `$scope` instead of `scope`. Is this just a typo?

Comment: `scope = $rootScope.$new();` Always depends on how you inject it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on your comment I think you don't need any `expect($scope.$on).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...);` since it makes sure that something really listens the event.

In order to assert the event is fired you have to prepare everything necessary and then perform the action leading to the event broadcast. I guess the spec could be outlined in following manner:

```
it('should fire "event:auth-loginRequired" event in case of 401', function() {
    var flag = false;
    var listener = jasmine.createSpy('listener');
    scope.$on('event:auth-loginRequired', listener);
    $httpBackend.when('GET', myApi.config.apiRoot + '/user').respond(401, '');

    runs(function() {
        myApi.get(function(error, success) {
            // this never gets triggered as 401 are intercepted
        });
        setTimeout(function() {
            flag = true;
        }, 1000);
    });

    waitsFor(function() {
        return flag;
    }, 'should be completed', 1200);

    runs(function() {
        expect(listener).toHaveBeenCalled();        
    });
});
```

Comment: The code looks reasonable, but unfortunately it doesn't work. The event gets fired after get(), but it's asynchronous.

Comment: So in this case Jasmine has also asynchronous support. Could Jasmine `runs` and `waitsFor` be useful for that? It allows you to wait for a while in the spec. See the Jasmine doc here: http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/#section-Asynchronous_Support